# С плеча, или сплеча?

Tags: грамматика

Рубанув с плеча, он предложил переночевать у него в гостях.

Answer (score 1):

Как? сплеча(резко) - наречие, пишется слитно, только фраза какая-то странная. Он что-то резкое сказал?

Comment: После трехминутного знакомства, брунеец (в своей стране) приглашает незнакомого иностранца в гости. Резко, в значении "грубо" - нет. Неожиданно.

Comment: "Неожиданно" не есть "сплеча". Фраза действительно странная.

Comment: Это было опубликовано в газете, и мой вариант - "раздельный" был заменен редактором на "слитный".

Comment: Ну, газеты бывают разные... Но с точки зрения грамматики редактор прав.

Comment: Газета была не "желтая". Выходит, заменить нужно на "внезапно", или же "с бухты-барахты" ?

Comment: "Совершенно неожиданно" или "внезапно" было бы лучше.